# kubernetes getting Internal error occurred: failed to allocate a serviceIP: range is full when creating service w. nodeport.

Tags: kubernetes

We have 254 nodeports currently in use (we have a number of environments sharing a cluster) and are using the default range.  Is there a api parameter that I'm not seeing to bump this limit up?

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to change the `--service-cluster-ip-range=` on the [kube-api-server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/).